# Databricks - dbfs:/mnt/ question in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm new with this of Databricks in Azure Data Factory.
Right now we got a Pipeline that contains only one single python activity. As you can see there is a dynamic file location that shows this : @concat('dbfs:/mnt/folder1/folder2/',pipeline().parameters.Input.pythonFile,'.py')

[image]

My question is, what is exactly this location **dbfs:/mnt** . How can I check where it is pointing.

I try to follow this article :

https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#special-dbfs-root-locations

However I do not see the DBFS tab that it mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/mnt/<something>` is the place where people are usually mount external storage accounts that are outside of the DBFS root filesystem.  You can find to which storage it's pointing by using the `dbutils.fs.mounts()` command executed in the notebook in Databricks (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#mounts-command-dbutilsfsmounts))